# Yii Framework - beginWidget without echo

Tags: php, forms, yii

I use this code to create my form:

```
$form=$controller->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'my-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false
    ));
```

When I do this, it prints the form. But I want to put this in a variable, because the entire form is returned as string in the method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following takes the output buffer, stores it into a variable and then erases it. Enjoy!!!

```
ob_start();

$form=$controller->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'my-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false
    ));

$formToStore =  ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: George, thank for the solution. It's a way to do that, but what is the colateral effect in use ob_start and ob_get_clean?

Comment: No effect.... It just forces the output into a string instead..... This is very commonly used as a method to later cache elements of a page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the controller's renderPartial method to return a string. Simply put your entire form in a file by itself, let's call it `_myForm.php`.

Then use this line to write the form contents to the variable `$form`:

```
$form = $controller->renderPartial('//stuff/_myForm', $data, true);
```

The 3rd parameter set to `true` will return the contents of that renderPartial, instead of echoing. That includes 'overriding' the echoing of the widget itself.

The `$data` parameter includes any variables you need to pass to the form.

The file itself will need to be in the `protected/views/stuff/` folder. The `//` start to the first parameter is a shortcut for the `protected/views/` folder.

Alternately, use just `'_myForm'` for the first parameter if that file is in the same views folder as where the renderPartial is called from.

Note: this is not really functionally different than the option to use `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`. It is simply the more Yii way to do it. There may be an advantage to one version over the other depending on the specifics of your situation.

Comment: Willem, thank for the solution. It's another way to do, but, as George's solution, it's look weird, because i will need to create a file only to use a widget inside a function.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Specifically the function and purpose for its existence. Historically I've never had need of putting a form inside of a function, so perhaps we can find a solution you'll like if we understand your purpose better.